# jquery mousewheel plugin: how to fire only one function every scroll

Tags: jquery, mousewheel

i'm using a moushweel plugin because i want my user to fire an action everytime it scroll up or down, but i dont want to have multiples fires (if you have a apple magic Mouse it is even worse because is too sensitive)

any idea on how to prevent it?

this is the code

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('div.mousewheel_example')
        .bind('mousewheel', function(event, delta) {
            var dir = delta > 0 ? 'Up' : 'Down',
                vel = Math.abs(delta);
            $(this).text(dir + ' at a velocity of ' + vel);
            return false;
        });
});
```

this is the plugin page
http://brandonaaron.net/code/mousewheel/demos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try playing with [window.setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout). Maybe by pulling out your nested function and using something a proxy function with a timer. Example:

```
var timer; 

function proxyFunction(){
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout("mouseWheelAction", 1);
}
```

This will not stop the event firing but it will stop your function from running everytime the event fires.

Answer (score 0):

Sicck, got it.
If you are running an animation inside just preface it with .stop()
So it would read

```
$('#findme').stop().animate(...);
```